# How do I setup a Letsencrypt ssl certificate on Xeams mail server?

Tags: java, email, ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt

First, I was able to successfully setup a letsencrypt certificate on an Ubuntu 14.0.4 server for my domain, and I  confirmed everything was okay, by verifying I could access my domain via https and checking that I really did have the correct files in:

`/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/`

I have a Xeams mail server running on the server and I've been finding it difficult following the steps in the [guide](http://www.xeams.com/usingssl.htm). First I had to convert the cert files generated by LetsEncrypt from `.pem` to `.crt` using:

`openssl x509 -outform der -in my-cert.pem -out my-cert.crt`

Which worked fine and converted the files successfully, but the problem I have with the guide is that, It assumes I don't already have an ssl certificate which isn't the case. I don't think I should have to generate a CSR code again when I already have the certificate from Letsencrypt.

To be clear, these are the cert files I have for my domain.

1. cert.pem
2. chain.pem
3. privkey.pem
4. fullchain.pem

But in the guide, it requires me generating CSR codes and whatnot, I have skipped generating a CSR to the part where I have to add the certificates to the keystore, but Its not very straightforward what I'm supposed to do, cause the files in the guide aren't correlating with what I have gotten from Letsencrypt.

When I try to follow the rest of the guide, and test that my server accepts connections on Secure IMAP port: 995 , my server returns a self signed certificate and not the certificate from the CA.

I used openssl to test the secure IMAP port 995

`openssl s_client -connect localhost:995`

I also confirmed Letsencrypt support for ssl email protocols and Java, so there has to be something I am not getting right. I have not been able to figure out how to add my certificates to the keystore.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: *"My server returns a self signed certificate and not the certificate from the CA..."* - You are mis-configured. The server is serving the the default site's certificate to the user agent. You usually avoid it by using TLS and SNI: `openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:995 -tls1 -servername mail.example.com`.

Comment: @jww Oh my bad! Can you move the question to the relevant site please?

Comment: @jww I also get this `No client certificate CA names sent` in the reponse.